# GraphQL mutation in Svelte to submit a comment in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, graphql, svelte, wp-graphql

How to submit a comment in svelte using Graphql? 
My svelte code is like this

```
<script>
    let commenterMessage = '';
    export let status = false;

    export async function submitComment() {
        $: commenterMessage;
        const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(import.meta.env.VITE_GRAPHCMS_URL, {
            headers: {}
        });

        const query = gql`
            mutation CREATE_COMMENT {
                createComment(
                    input: {
                        commentOn: 115
                        content: ${commenterMessage}
                        author: "Sarah Jason"
                    }
                ) {
                    success
                    comment {
                        id
                        content
                        author {
                            node {
                                name
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `;

        const { createComment } = await graphcms.request(query);
        return {
            props: {
                status: createComment.success
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

And this is the form that I use binding values from user:

```
<form id="comment_form" method="post">
    <div class="group-val ct-gr">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Comment" bind:value={commenterMessage} />
    </div>
    <a
        href="#"
        class="btn fill"
        on:click|preventDefault={submitComment}
        data-text="Add Comment">
        Add Comment
    </a>
</form>
```

I have and error for `${commenterMessage}` in gql query.
This is the error that I see in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character ".".: {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character \".\".","extensions":{"category":"graphql"},"locations":[{"line":6,"column":21}]}],"extensions":{"debug":[{"type":"DUPLICATE_FIELD","message":"You cannot register duplicate fields on the same Type. The field 'theme' already exists on the type 'RootQuery'. Make sure to give the field a unique name.","field_name":"theme","type_name":"RootQuery","stack":["E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Registry\\TypeRegistry.php:1025","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:305","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\plugin.php:189","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Type\\WPObjectType.php:226","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Type\\WPObjectType.php:126","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\FieldDefinition.php:96","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\TypeWithFields.php:26","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\TypeWithFields.php:61","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Utils\\InstrumentSchema.php:32","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:303","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\plugin.php:189","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Registry\\TypeRegistry.php:826","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Registry\\SchemaRegistry.php:40","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\WPGraphQL.php:601","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Request.php:146","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Router.php:464","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Router.php:270","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:303","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:327","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\plugin.php:518","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp.php:388","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp.php:750","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\functions.php:1291","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-blog-header.php:16","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\index.php:17"]},{"type":"DUPLICATE_FIELD","message":"You cannot register duplicate fields on the same Type. The field 'categories' already exists on the type 'RootQuery'. Make sure to give the field a unique name.","field_name":"categories","type_name":"RootQuery","stack":["E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Registry\\TypeRegistry.php:1025","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:305","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\plugin.php:189","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Type\\WPObjectType.php:226","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Type\\WPObjectType.php:126","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\FieldDefinition.php:96","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\TypeWithFields.php:26","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\TypeWithFields.php:61","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Utils\\InstrumentSchema.php:32","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:303","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\plugin.php:189","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Registry\\TypeRegistry.php:826","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Registry\\SchemaRegistry.php:40","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\WPGraphQL.php:601","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Request.php:146","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Router.php:464","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Router.php:270","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:303","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:327","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\plugin.php:518","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp.php:388","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp.php:750","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\functions.php:1291","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-blog-header.php:16","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\index.php:17"]},{"type":"DUPLICATE_FIELD","message":"You cannot register duplicate fields on the same Type. The field 'themes' already exists on the type 'RootQuery'. Make sure to give the field a unique name.","field_name":"themes","type_name":"RootQuery","stack":["E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Registry\\TypeRegistry.php:1025","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:305","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\plugin.php:189","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Type\\WPObjectType.php:226","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Type\\WPObjectType.php:126","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\FieldDefinition.php:96","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\TypeWithFields.php:26","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\vendor\\webonyx\\graphql-php\\src\\Type\\Definition\\TypeWithFields.php:61","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Utils\\InstrumentSchema.php:32","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:303","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\plugin.php:189","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Registry\\TypeRegistry.php:826","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Registry\\SchemaRegistry.php:40","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\WPGraphQL.php:601","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Request.php:146","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Router.php:464","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-content\\plugins\\wp-graphql\\src\\Router.php:270","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:303","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php:327","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\plugin.php:518","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp.php:388","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\class-wp.php:750","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-includes\\functions.php:1291","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\wp-blog-header.php:16","E:\\wamp64\\www\\simplecv\\cms\\index.php:17"]}]},"status":200,"headers":{"map":{"content-length":"7395","content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"}}},"request":{"query":"\n\t\t\tmutation CREATE_COMMENT {\n\t\t\t\tcreateComment(\n\t\t\t\t\tinput: {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tcommentOn: 115\n\t\t\t\t\t\tcontent: Hello. This is the message from the form.\n\t\t\t\t\t\tauthor: \"ali akizade\"\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t) {\n\t\t\t\t\tsuccess\n\t\t\t\t\tcomment {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tid\n\t\t\t\t\t\tcontent\n\t\t\t\t\t\tauthor {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tnode {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tname\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t"}}
```

How can I use the value that user types in form input?

Comment: play with admin playground **before coding** - eliminate errors in custom types/fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `content: ${commenterMessage}` that I should have written like this:

```
content: "${commenterMessage}"
```

as the content is a ***String*** we should surround it with double quotes.